# Why did JSP file is not loading in springboot?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, jsp

I was making a basic springboot project in which from controller I am calling jsp file to display but it is not showing and it is giving me error.

```
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Fri Aug 25 05:00:19 IST 2023
There was an unexpected error (type=Not Found, status=404).
```

Can anyone please tell why 404 error is coming?

Here is my project structure

[image]

Here are few files

This is my controller file

```
@Controller
public class MainController {

    @GetMapping("/home")
    public String home()
    {
        System.out.println("hello in home");
        return "home";
    }

    @RequestMapping("/contact")
    @ResponseBody
    public String contact()
    {
        return "In contact";
    }

}
```

This is my application.properties file

```
server.port=8585
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

And in last this is my pom.xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.springboot.learn</groupId>
    <artifactId>project</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>project</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>10.1.10</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is the version of your Tomcat, it should be version 10. Spring Boot 3 does not work with Tomcat 9 due to the package being renamed from javax to jakarta.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-jasper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>10.1.10</version>
        </dependency>
```

I just followed one of basic examples and it is working as expected.
Here are the snippets.

Main Class

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;

@SpringBootApplication
public class DemoApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(DemoApplication.class, args);
    }

}
```

Controller class

```
package com.example.demo.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;

@Controller
public class HomeController {

    @GetMapping("/")
    public String showJsp() {

        return "foo";
    }

}
```

application.properties

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/views/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
```

And jsp page placed in this position

```
demo\src\main\webapp\views\foo.jsp
```

And pom.xml just in case

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.3</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.example</groupId>
    <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>demo</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.tomcat.embed/tomcat-embed-jasper -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <version>10.1.10</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

I don't know what your class ServletInitializer is, but if it is a component you need to move it to the subpackage of your main class location in order for it to be scanned, as you can see from my example it is not required.

If needed here is a picture of the project structure

[image]

Here is the blog I used to create this demo project

https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-jsp

Comment: thanks,  i changed the version but its still not working.
Can I share a link of repo of it to provide more details.

Comment: @zawaudo I have removed ServletInitializer class also, can you plz share your jsp file also

Comment: it just has this <p>This is a paragraph.</p>

Comment: and I visit http://localhost:8080/ since i mapped the controller to "/" and that's it

Comment: oh, okay but it still it gives me 404 error on hitting URL, project structure is also same

public String home()
    {
        System.out.println("hello in home");
        return "home";
    }
I am doing like this but in console "hello in home" is printing which basically means that something in not working in jsp while returning from controller function

If you know something related to this @zawarudo

Comment: it might be the issue with the fact that you are using vscode instead of intellij, because as I said, I shared a working solution that I wrote and tested on my machine.

Comment: if you copy the code and follow the structure that i provided it will work.

Comment: I have provided the code so can you run my code on intellij, it will let me know whether there is any problem with IDE or not
Just need copy, paste but it will help me

Comment: code that you provided still has Tomcat 9 instead of 10, Spring Boot 3 does not work with Tomcat 9, i stated that in my answer

Comment: yeh I have made changes here now, plz run on intellij and let me know if it woking on hitting localhost:8585/home or not?

Comment: http://localhost:8585/home is working fine, right click on main class > run as java > visit http://localhost:8585/home

Comment: Its still not working for me, if I think this is a issue with VS code that is weird I guess as lot of people using with VS code.
Any suggestions yours on this?

Comment: VS code requires installation of plugins for spring to work on it, it is not designed to be used for spring development out of the box. My suggestion is to use intellij like everyone else.